# Consequence of Baire Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

So, the Baire theorem I know is the following:

---

**Theorem:** Let $\{U_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a collection of open dense sets $U_n \subset \mathbb{R}$, then $U:={\bigcap_{n}(U_n)}$ is dense

---

**Question:** with this result in mind, is it possible to show that a dense set (for example U) can't be written as the countable union of empty sets with empty interior? I think I saw this statement somewhere, but could not prove it.

My idea was to simply take the complement of the theorem above.

This would give me $U^c={\bigcup_{n}(U_n^c)}$ where all $U_n^c$ have empty interior (because they are complements of dense sets). But I can't see how I use this to show that my set $U$ can't be written as something like that.

Comment: Countable union of *empty sets*? If you just impose that these sets are of empty interior, then the statement is false: $\mathbb Q\subseteq\mathbb R$ is dense, and it is countable therefore is a countable union of sets with empty interiors.

Comment: By $U_n\in\mathbb R$ I think you mean $U_n\subseteq\mathbb R$.

Comment: The statement you were thinking of: probably "$\Bbb R$ cannot be written as a countable union of sets $A_n$ whose closure has empty interior (so-called "nowhere dense" sets).

Comment: (cont.) and that you can prove by showing $\Bbb R\setminus \overline{A_n}$ is dense and open for such $A_n$ and applying de Morgan to get a contradiction.

Comment: $\Bbb Q=\cup_{q\in \Bbb Q}\{q\}$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ and is a countable union of closed nowhere-dense sets.

Comment: If $S\subset \Bbb R$ and $S$ has non-empty interior , and if $T=\{t_n:n\in \Bbb N\}$ is a family of subsets of $\Bbb R$ such that $int(\bar t)=\emptyset$ for all $t\in T,$ then $\cup T\ne S.$ Because $V=\{\Bbb R \setminus \bar t: t\in T\}$ is a non-empty countable family of dense open sets, so $U= \cap V$ is dense. So $\emptyset \ne U\cap int(S)\subset S\setminus \cup T.$